# Route calls audio to earpiece Android M

Tags: android, audio, android-6.0-marshmallow, audio-route

I would like to hear audio calls from earpiece and speak with default smartphone's microphone when earphones are plugged in.

I read lot of questions on stackoverflow but nothing of them works with Android M (developer preview).

Thare are a lot of methods deprecated that seem not work.
Has anyone got a solution for that?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: On the devices I've worked on, voice calls would always be routed to the wired headset/headphone if one is attached. The internal earpiece is only used when there's no suitable accessory to route the call audio to.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for reply! Is it possible that we don't have any api or some hack solution to ignore earphones plugged in and use the default earpiece/microphone? I try also some play store app like SoundAbout but it doesn't work too with Android M DP ...